# Using sed to delete everything but the first three characters before a delimiter?

Tags: unix

So this command will delete everything in the line except the first 3 characters:

```
sed -r 's/(.{3}).*/\1/'
```

How do I do it so it stops at the first comma?

e.g

1.45232, red, fast

would result in

1.45, red, fast?

Comment: 1.45 are 4 chars. Do you want output `1.4, red, fast` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed -r 's/.*(.{3})/\1/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/^(.{3})[^,]*,/\1,/' file
```

Output:

```
452, red, fast
```